# Having a hard time writing a proof in Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $S$ be a set of nonzero polynomials in $P(F)$ such that no two have
the same degree. Prove that $S$ is linearly independent.

I tried writing the solution as follows:

Let $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$ be some polynomials in $S.$ Arranging them in ascending order of their degrees and re labeling them as $f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ we have $$\deg(f_1)\lt \deg(f_2)\lt\cdots\lt\deg(f_n)=d_n.$$

Let $c_1,c_2,c_3,....,c_n$ be some scalars such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_if_i=0,$ which is a polynomial of degree $d_n$ and as $\sum_{i=1}^n c_if_i=0\implies c_i=0\implies S$ is linearly independent as, $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$are any arbitrary polynomials.

---

Now, the point is, I know that the way I have written out the solution looks ambiguous and lacks clarity, but I don't know how to improve it either? Also, I understand why the claim in the question is true, but somehow I am unable to choose the right phrases, words and symbols to express it correctly.

Comment: Can you justify your implication $\sum_{i=1}^n c_if_i=0\implies c_i=0$ any further? This looks to me like assuming what you have to prove.

Comment: You haven't proven linear independence. You've *invoked* linear independence. You need to prove the $f_i$ are linearly independent. Instead, once you have $\sum_{i=1}^n c_if_i=0$, deduce that $c_n$ must be zero (by degree considerations), and therefore that $c_{n-1}$ must be zero... etc. That will show the $f_i$ (which are the same as the $g_i$, but in some other order) are linearly independent.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To be very frank, that is my idea i.e trying to show $c_n=0$ which will imply $c_{n-1}=0$ and so on. But the problem is, hiw to show rigorously that $c_n=0$ ? I think we have to start with the $f_i's$ explicitly written out in polynomial form, but that get's messy for me.

Comment: Think about the leafing term of the sum, in light of the fact that the degrees are strictly increasing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If I am getting you correctly, then the leading term of the term of the sum will be $$c_ka_kx^{d_n}+c_{k-1}(\cdots)+\cdots +c_1(\cdots)=0$$ where,  $a_kx^{d_n}$ is the leading term of the polynomial $f_k$. But I don't think we can conclude, $c_k=0$ directly as of yet. Also, this makes my problem precise, if not complicated.

Comment: You don't want to conclude $a_k=0$ (actually, $a_{d_n}$). You want to conclude $c_k=0$ (actually, $c_n$) which **must** be the case because $a_k\neq 0$ and the zero polynomial has all coefficients  equal to zero. This does not make your problem complicated, it makes it *trivial*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok, let me try to express myself better since things are becoming clearer. I have seen generally, we refer to $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$$ a zero polynomial if $f(x)=0,\forall x\in$ the domain of $f$. Now, the polynomial I wrote out earlier i.e $c_ka_kx^{d_n}+c_{k-1}(\cdots)+\cdots +c_1(\cdots)=0.$ I am not sure whether I can call this a zero polynomial or not. This is because, the form of this $$c_ka_kx^{d_n}+c_{k-1}(\cdots)+\cdots +c_1(...)=0$$ does not matches with the form of 
 $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0=0$$ because the $(...)'s$ are not any powers of $x$

Comment: Doesn't matter. Everything in the parentheses has degree **strictly smaller** than $d_n$, so even if you did all those calculations, they would not affect the coefficient of $x^{d_n}$. So you already know that coefficient and can conclude $c_n$ must equal zero.

Comment: @ThomasFinley: If $\deg(f_1)=n$ and $\deg(f_2),\ldots,\deg(f_k)\lt n$, then for any constants $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, the leading term of $a_1f_1+\cdots+a_kf_k$ is the leading term of $f_1$ multiplied by $a_1$. You don't need to do all the calculations, all you need is to identify the leading term and note that if that linear combination is the zero polynomial, then you must have $a_1=0$ as a consequence.